# Where is the best place to store a site specific setting?

Tags: python, django

So I'd like to be able to store a site-specific setting for example, `SITE_MODE = foo`.

Where I'd like to use the setting is in the HTML templates e.g.

```
{% if SITE_MODE == 'foo' %}
    <p>Show this</>
{% elif SITE_MODE == 'bar' %}
    <p>Or do this </p>
{% endif %}
```

I know there is obviously my *settings.py* or *local_settings.py* but i'm not sure i can reference the values from the views or templates? Ideally this would be stored in the database somewhere but i'm not sure of the best place to put it. was keen to find out what the pros do!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I know there is obviously my settings.py or local_settings.py but i'm
>   not sure i can reference the values from the views or templates?

You can reference anything in your template if you pass the variable/value to the template through its context.

```
#settings.py
SITE_MODE = 'foo'
```

Then in your `views.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

def my_view(request):
some_data= get_some_data_to_be_passed_to_template()
return render(request, 'path/to/my_template.html', {'data': some_data, SITE_MODE: settings.SITE_MODE})
```

Then in your `template.html`, you will be able to access `SITE_MODE`:

```
{% if SITE_MODE == 'foo' %}
    <p>Show this</>
{% elif SITE_MODE == 'bar' %}
    <p>Or do this </p>
{% endif %}
```

Note: `SITE_MODE` is most likely a global setting. Hence I declared it inside `settings.py` under `my_project` directory. If I have a setting specific to an app(A project can have multiple apps), I would create a `settings.py` file under `my_app` and declare my settings specific to that app.

```
my_app1
    --settings.py #local to my_app1
my_app2
    --settings.py #local to my_app2
my_project
    --settings.py #global to all apps
```